# "pip install -e ." equivalent for npm/typescript/react

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm developing a central set of React (Typescript) components that need to be imported from several other projects that are in development as well. When I face this type of situation in Python, I would use `pip install -e .` from the virtual env of each dependent project. Then I can use `from central_package import xyz` from wherever.

What is the equivalent procedure for React/Typescript? I have tried `npm link`, but there seems to be an issue with importing the components:

`Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.`

I'm assuming some particular setup is required.

Answer (score 1):

> What is the equivalent procedure for React/Typescript

There is no global *dependency* pattern supported. Each project that depends on e.g. `react` will have it as a `devDependency`.